# How do I output the product of two matrices in matrix form?

Tags: matrix, output

I am working on Haar Bivariate filters, and I would like to show the final matrix after applying the 4 filters.  Here is the code that I have so far.  I would like the final output to be in matrix form.

[image]

Comment: Well as the red curly brackets indicate `Partition` is not used as a function method here: try `Partition[...]//MartixForm` .

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with:

`MatrixA = {{a, b}, {c, d}};`

`MatrixB = {{e, f}, {g, h}};`

`MatrixForm[MatrixA*MatrixB]`?